# Website redirects to wrong url on first load

Tags: javascript, php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have created a website for a friend of mine and I have used a .htaccess to redirect make each page display without the .php extension so visionltd.co.uk/masonry-support.php becomes visionltd.co.uk/masonry-support.

I thought it was working fine, however I have noticed that when I first click on one of the navigation links, it still shows the page with .php, yet if I then click on another link, or the same link again, it reverts to not showing .php.

I have looked at the .htaccess over and over but can't see anything immediately wrong with it.

So I am asking you gurus for a bit of help pointing me in the right direction. The site is visionltd.co.uk. I have included the .htaccess code below.

Thanks

Andy

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# enforce www prefix
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.visionltd\.co.uk$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://visionltd.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /index.html http://visionltd.co.uk/index
Redirect 301 /about-us.html http://visionltd.co.uk/about-us
Redirect 301 /brickwork-savings-comparison.html http://visionltd.co.uk/brickwork-savings-comparison
Redirect 301 /case-studies.html http://visionltd.co.uk/case-studies
Redirect 301 /contact-us.html http://visionltd.co.uk/contact-us
Redirect 301 /health-and-safety.html http://visionltd.co.uk/health-and-safety
Redirect 301 /masonry-restraint-ties.html http://visionltd.co.uk/masonry-restraint-ties
Redirect 301 /masonry-support.html http://visionltd.co.uk/masonry-support
Redirect 301 /testimonials.html http://visionltd.co.uk/customer-testimonials
Redirect 301 /wall-tie-comparison.html http://visionltd.co.uk/wall-tie-comparison
Redirect 301 /windposts.html http://visionltd.co.uk/windposts
Redirect 301 /news.html http://visionltd.co.uk/news

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

<Files ~ “^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])”>
order allow,deny
deny from all
satisfy all
</Files>
```

Comment: The PHP file for the home page is still outputting the URIs with the `.php` extension. Remove those and it'll work fine.

Comment: OMG! what an idiot I am, I totally forgot I have two navigation includes running. Mike Rockett, thank you very much, I had checked one but neglected the other. Problem solved and it was a simple one thank goodness!